# Need to Evaluate strlen of an XML

Tags: php, xml, rss, strlen

Hopefully this is simple.

In PHP I am trying to scrape some RSSfeeds. Sometimes, the RSS feed is not properly updated/populated, yet it is **NOT** an empty file. I have the following code:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file("feed-url-here");    
if ($xml != "") {       
    if (strlen($xml) > 600) {
        perform some actions here;
    }
}
```

This does not work. Is there a quick way to evaluate the strlen of an xml?

Hopefully something that does not involve parsing the feed itself.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Im not sure what you want to achieve,anyway if you want to get the lenght of the string that represents the xml, you can do it like this:

```
   $xml = simplexml_load_file("feed-url-here");
   if ($xml != "") {       
      if (strlen($xml->asXML()) > 600) {
           perform some actions here; 
      }
   }
```